# Faded palindrome where I want to remove the '.'(dot) charcter from the String

Tags: java

I am getting output as I want but when the test case is like

> kaj.jak

my output is coming as

> kaj.jak

but what I want is

> kajjak

Here I want to remove '.'.  How would I go about doing this?
below is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String strstr = s.next();
        int len = strstr.length();
        char[] str = strstr.toCharArray();
        int flag = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
            if (str[i] != str[len - 1 - i]) {
                if (str[i] == '.')
                    str[i] = str[len - 1 - i];
                else if (str[len - 1 - i] == '.')
                    str[len - 1 - i] = str[i];
                else
                    flag = 1;
            } else if (str[i] == '.' && str[len - 1 - i] == '.') {
                str[i] = '';//one more thing here i am getting error as empty character literals
                str[len - 1 - j] = '';
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag == 1)
        System.out.println(-1);
    else
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: @NicholasK:  OP did; they input "kaj.jak", they get back "kaj.jak", and they want "kajjak".

Comment: So I took a stab at reformatting your code.  I haven't touched any of the braces or anything like that; this is how it came up.  This code **does not compile**.

Comment: if my input is a.ba the n my output is abba.here dot is getting replaced by 'b' so as to make the string as palindrome but when my input is kaj.jak then i want to remove the '.' so that the string will become palindrome

Comment: @Makoto as i already told that it is giving me compile time error.but if i replace that ' ' with some character like 'a' then the code is working fine

Comment: I see.  So your issue *is* the compilation errors.  I understand now.

Comment: actually my issue is with that dot character which i want to remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very clear with your question, but if you're trying to just remove a `.`, then use the following code

```
strstr = strstr.replace(".", "");
```

Comment: i tried it but its giving same result.just tell me something related to character what i  have taken

Comment: Are you trying to find the palindrome of a String or just trying to replace a character in the String?

Comment: its a faded palindrome,if there is possibilities of making the string in palindrome the just print the palindrome string otherwise print "-1"

Comment: Ok. So now after you *find* the palindrome all you need to do is check if it contains a `.` and replace that with `""`.

Comment: any other solution for that

Comment: In your else block try this : `System.out.println(str.replace(".", ""));`

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you looking:
also her '\0' is empty char; for some compiler it may display space.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String strstr = s.next();
        int len = strstr.length();
        char[] str = strstr.toCharArray();
        int flag = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < (len / 2)+1; i++) {
            if (str[i] != str[len - 1 - i]) {
                if (str[i] == '.')
                    str[i] = str[len - 1 - i];
                else if (str[len - 1 - i] == '.')
                    str[len - 1 - i] = str[i];
                else
                    flag = 1;
            } else if (str[i] == '.' && str[len - 1 - i] == '.') {
                str[i] = '\0';//one more thing here i am getting error as empty character literals
               str[len - 1 - i] = '\0';
            }
        }

    if(flag==1)
                   System.out.println(-1);
    else
            System.out.println(str);
}
```

}

Comment: it's not worth.its giving the input alone

Comment: i/p: ka.jak
o/p: kajjak
i/p: kaj.jak
o/p:kajjak

is anything else you wanted.. give some sample i/p and o/p

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanna remove . from your char string you can just do this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your Strings: ");
    char[] str = s.next().toCharArray();
    int flag = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if(str[i] == '.'){
            str[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        if(str[i] == '.') 
            flag = 1;
        else
            flag = 0;
    }
if(flag == 1)
    System.out.println(-1);
else
    System.out.println(str);

}
```

Edit:
btw you use `''` in `str[len - 1 - i] = ''` and that's wrong use 0 instead char takes values not strings

Comment: btw also idk why in for loop you use strstr.length() / 2 u can just use your char length and why div by 2 anyway if you wanna delete any "." in your string then let it go for full loop and remove it.